# Right align section title on odd pages & left align on even pages in Memoir class

Tags: memoir

Does anyone know how to left align section headings (so `\raggedright`) when they are on even pages (the normal behaviour for documents) but also to right align (so `\raggedleft`) them on odd pages (what I've shown in the MWE below)?

I've put a picture of the two pages of code below with an arrow showing what I want added to it.

I know `\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}` puts all section headings to the right of the page - but I need them to alternate on even and odd pages. I read somewhere this is easier in memoir than in the book class but I can't even begin to guess how to do it. Very new to memoir!

Thanks for any advice you may have.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% chapter always aligns right which is fine as chapters only appear on odd numbered pages
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}

%% I want even page sections to be \raggedright and viceversa so they will match the headers (not shown in this MWE)

\setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\raggedleft} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of chapter 1}
\section{sec 1}
\clearpage
\section{sec 2}


\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1 = fine]

[image: How do I do this?]

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there --- use `memoir`'s `\checkoddpage` macro. In your `memoir` preamble put:

```
% \strictpagecheck % uncomment if problems at new pages
\newcommand{\oddright}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\raggedleft\fi}
\setsecheadstyle{\oddright\Large\bfseries}
```

If you want a similar effect for `\subsection` then add

```
\setsubsecheadstyle{\oddright\large\bfseries}
```

See sections 18.12 and 6.6 in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for further information about odd/even page checking and changing the style of sectional headings.

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer I was looking for. I knew there'd be a memoir specific way of doing it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** - I realise your question is about how to implement this using the `memoir` class, which has its own built in tools which match the functionality of packages like `titlesec`. But, until someone posts a `memoir` solution, here is a way to do it using `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe} %<---- Just for testing

%% chapter always aligns right which is fine as chapters only appear on odd numbered pages
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}{\large\bfseries\raggedleft}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}{\large\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of chapter 1}
\section{sec 1}
\clearpage
\section{sec 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]